# Elements Arrangement For Calculating Mean In Python/NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have 1-d list as follows:

```
data = [1,5,9,13,
        2,6,10,14,
        3,7,11,15,
        4,8,12,16]
```

I want to make the following list of tuples, and calculate mean of each tuple separately.

```
[(1,5,2,6), (3,7,4,8), (9,13,10,14), (11,15,12,16)]
```

The expected result should be:

```
[3.5, 5.5, 11.5, 13.5]
```

What is the easier way of doing it?

Comment: Did you have tried anything so far?maybe a search or any code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the data into a 4-d numpy array with shape (2, 2, 2, 2), then take  the mean of that array over axes 1 and 3:

```
In [25]: data
Out[25]: [1, 5, 9, 13, 2, 6, 10, 14, 3, 7, 11, 15, 4, 8, 12, 16]

In [26]: a = np.array(data).reshape(2, 2, 2, 2)

In [27]: a
Out[27]: 
array([[[[ 1,  5],
         [ 9, 13]],

        [[ 2,  6],
         [10, 14]]],


       [[[ 3,  7],
         [11, 15]],

        [[ 4,  8],
         [12, 16]]]])

In [28]: a.mean(axis=(1, 3))
Out[28]: 
array([[  3.5,  11.5],
       [  5.5,  13.5]])
```

You can use the `ravel()` method if you need the final result as a 1-d array:

```
In [31]: a.mean(axis=(1, 3)).ravel()
Out[31]: array([  3.5,  11.5,   5.5,  13.5])
```

See [How can I vectorize the averaging of 2x2 sub-arrays of numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26871083/how-can-i-vectorize-the-averaging-of-2x2-sub-arrays-of-numpy-array/) for a similar question.

Comment: First time saw axis=(1, 3), what's its meaning?

Comment: What if I have a large size array (say n  = 2000) and need to calculate the mean in the similar way?

Comment: @Borys I think it would be `a = np.array(data).reshape(-1, N1, M2/N2, N2)`, where `M2` = Columns in input data or stepsize (if you would like to call it that way for a 1D input list) and `N1, N2` = Blocksize into which data is to be divided and averaged.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach

```
In [29]: a = np.array(data)

In [30]: a2 = a.reshape(4,4)

In [31]: a3 = np.vstack((a2[:, :2], a2[:, 2:]))

In [32]: a4 = a3.reshape(4,4)

In [33]: np.mean(a4, axis=1)
Out[33]: array([  3.5,   5.5,  11.5,  13.5])
```

Answer (score 1):

Listed in this post are some solution suggestions -

```
def grouped_mean(data,M2,N1,N2):

    # Paramters:
    # M2 = Columns in input data
    # N1, N2 = Blocksize into which data is to be divided and averaged

    # Get grouped mean values; transpose and flatten for final output
    grouped_mean = np.array(data).reshape(-1,N2).sum(1).reshape(-1,N1,M2/N2).sum(1)/(N1*N2)

    # Return transposed and flattened version as output (as per OP) 
    return grouped_mean.T.ravel()
```

Now, `grouped_mean` could be calculated with [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) instead of `np.sum` like so -

```
stage1_sum = np.einsum('ij->i',np.array(data).reshape(-1,N2))
grouped_mean = np.einsum('ijk->ik',stage1_sum.reshape(-1,N1,M2/N2))/(N1*N2)
```

Or, one can go in with splitting 2D input array to a 4D array as suggested in [`@Warren Weckesser's solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31494550/3293881) and then use `np.einsum` like so -

```
split_data = np.array(data).reshape(-1, N1, M2/N2, N2)
grouped_mean = np.einsum('ijkl->ik',split_data)/(N1*N2)
```

Sample run -

```
In [182]: data = np.array([[1,5,9,13],
     ...:                  [2,6,10,14],
     ...:                  [3,7,11,15],
     ...:                  [4,8,12,16]])

In [183]: grouped_mean(data,4,2,2)
Out[183]: array([  3.5,   5.5,  11.5,  13.5])
```

---

**Runtime tests**

Calculating `grouped_mean` seems to be the most computationally intensive part of the code. So, here's some runtime tests to calculate it with those three approaches -

```
In [174]: import numpy as np
     ...: # Setup parameters and input list
     ...: M2 = 4000
     ...: N1 = 2
     ...: N2 = 2
     ...: data = np.random.randint(0,9,(16000000)).tolist()
     ...: 

In [175]: %timeit np.array(data).reshape(-1,N2).sum(1).reshape(-1,N1,M2/N2).sum(1)/(N1*N2)
     ...: %timeit np.einsum('ijk->ik',np.einsum('ij->i',np.array(data).reshape(-1,N2)).reshape(-1,N1,M2/N2))/(N1*N2)
     ...: %timeit np.einsum('ijkl->ik',np.array(data).reshape(-1, N1, M2/N2, N2))/(N1*N2)
     ...: 
1 loops, best of 3: 2.2 s per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 2.12 s per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 2.1 s per loop
```