# Extract blocks or patches from NumPy Array

Tags: numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, scikit-image

I have a 2-d numpy array as follows:

```
a = np.array([[1,5,9,13],
              [2,6,10,14],
              [3,7,11,15],
              [4,8,12,16]]
```

I want to extract it into patches of 2 by 2 sizes with out repeating the elements.

**The answer should exactly be the same. This can be 3-d array or list with the same order of elements as below:**

```
[[[1,5],
 [2,6]],   

 [[3,7],
 [4,8]],

 [[9,13],
 [10,14]],

 [[11,15],
 [12,16]]]
```

How can do it easily?

In my real problem the size of a is (36, 72). I can not do it one by one. I want programmatic way of doing it.

Comment: I updated my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26871083/how-can-i-vectorize-the-averaging-of-2x2-sub-arrays-of-numpy-array/.  Given that question and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31494190/elements-arrangement-for-calculating-mean-in-python-numpy, I think we can close this one as a dupe.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Can you show me HERE how you would extract the patches as  I extracted mannually in my question?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser It's not about calculating mean as in oyur answer

Comment: I've already improved my explanation of how the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26871083/how-can-i-vectorize-the-averaging-of-2x2-sub-arrays-of-numpy-array/ works.   Did you see the part that begins "To generalize..."?  There are two steps: reshape the array to a 4-d array, and then average.   The reshaping part is the same as what you are asking, so I'd rather not duplicate that here.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I think your answer is more than sufficient for him to generalize to an answer (you gave the exact formula lol). It definitely puts my little baby python coder attempt to shame. I'm glad I looked at it.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser yes, I read your answer, but it does not show separate patches as I asked here. I have to extract separate patches. I hope you help me

Comment: In that answer, `y` is the array of "patches".  To access a patch, use `y[j, :, k, :]`.  In your case of an original array with shape (36, 72), `j` will vary from  0 to 17, and `k` will vary from 0 to 35.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I mean I want the patches as sub-metrics of the one array as the answer of this question

Comment: Ah, so if `a` is your input, you could just use `a[2*j:2*j+2, 2*k:2*k+2]`.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Can you put your 4d array with the exact  order of elements in my patches.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser j and k should be put through for loop?

Comment: To my mind, your collection of 2x2 patches is inherently a 2-d collection; `y` in the other answer can be interpreted as a 2-d array of 2-d patches.  If that doesn't work for you, could you modify the question to be more explicit about the desired data structure that you want in the end?  Maybe a python list of 2-d arrays?  Something else?  What are you going to do with this collection of patches?  (Preferably, you should edit the question to clarify rather than explaining it here in the comments.)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser yes I have edited my question describing the structure and order of elements is importnat.

Comment: @TrekkieByDay yes this is the only question remained to complete my MBA, lol!

Comment: Deleted my answer as @WarrenWeckesser provided a better one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a rather cryptic numpy one-liner to generate your 3-d array, called `result1` here:

```
In [60]: x
Out[60]: 
array([[2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2],
       [3, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 0],
       [2, 0, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 3, 3, 2, 0, 3, 2, 0, 3],
       [0, 1, 0, 3, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2],
       [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 3],
       [2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2],
       [0, 3, 3, 3, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1]])

In [61]: result1 = x.reshape(x.shape[0]//2, 2, x.shape[1]//2, 2).swapaxes(1, 2).reshape(-1, 2, 2)
```

`result1` is like a 1-d array of 2-d arrays:

```
In [68]: result1.shape
Out[68]: (20, 2, 2)

In [69]: result1[0]
Out[69]: 
array([[2, 1],
       [3, 1]])

In [70]: result1[1]
Out[70]: 
array([[2, 2],
       [2, 1]])

In [71]: result1[5]
Out[71]: 
array([[2, 0],
       [0, 1]])

In [72]: result1[-1]
Out[72]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 1]])
```

(Sorry, I don't have time at the moment to give a detailed breakdown of how it works.  Maybe later...)

Here's a less cryptic version that uses a nested list comprehension.  In this case, `result2` is a python list of 2-d numpy arrays:

```
In [73]: result2 = [x[2*j:2*j+2, 2*k:2*k+2] for j in range(x.shape[0]//2) for k in range(x.shape[1]//2)]

In [74]: result2[5]
Out[74]: 
array([[2, 0],
       [0, 1]])

In [75]: result2[-1]
Out[75]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 1]])
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for!

Comment: @Warren , you deserve a beer

Comment: How would you reverse this operation?

Answer (score 29):

Using scikit-image:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.util import view_as_blocks

a = np.array([[1,5,9,13],
              [2,6,10,14],
              [3,7,11,15],
              [4,8,12,16]])

print(view_as_blocks(a, (2, 2)))
```

Answer (score 15):

You can achieve it with a combination of [`np.reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) and [`np.swapaxes`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html) like so -

```
def extract_blocks(a, blocksize, keep_as_view=False):
    M,N = a.shape
    b0, b1 = blocksize
    if keep_as_view==0:
        return a.reshape(M//b0,b0,N//b1,b1).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(-1,b0,b1)
    else:
        return a.reshape(M//b0,b0,N//b1,b1).swapaxes(1,2)
```

As can be seen there are two ways to use it - With `keep_as_view` flag turned off (default one) or on. With `keep_as_view = False`, we are reshaping the swapped-axes to a final output of `3D`, while with `keep_as_view = True`, we will keep it 4D and that will be a view into the input array and hence, virtually free on runtime. We will verify it with a sample case run later on.

**Sample cases**

Let's use a sample input array, like so -

```
In [94]: a
Out[94]: 
array([[2, 2, 6, 1, 3, 6],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3],
       [4, 0, 0, 4, 1, 7],
       [3, 2, 4, 7, 2, 4],
       [8, 0, 7, 3, 4, 6],
       [1, 5, 6, 2, 1, 8]])
```

Now, let's use some block-sizes for testing. Let's use a blocksize of `(2,3)` with the view-flag turned off and on -

```
In [95]: extract_blocks(a, (2,3)) # Blocksize : (2,3)
Out[95]: 
array([[[2, 2, 6],
        [1, 0, 1]],

       [[1, 3, 6],
        [0, 0, 3]],

       [[4, 0, 0],
        [3, 2, 4]],

       [[4, 1, 7],
        [7, 2, 4]],

       [[8, 0, 7],
        [1, 5, 6]],

       [[3, 4, 6],
        [2, 1, 8]]])

In [48]: extract_blocks(a, (2,3), keep_as_view=True)
Out[48]: 
array([[[[2, 2, 6],
         [1, 0, 1]],

        [[1, 3, 6],
         [0, 0, 3]]],


       [[[4, 0, 0],
         [3, 2, 4]],

        [[4, 1, 7],
         [7, 2, 4]]],


       [[[8, 0, 7],
         [1, 5, 6]],

        [[3, 4, 6],
         [2, 1, 8]]]])
```

**Verify `view` with `keep_as_view=True`**

```
In [20]: np.shares_memory(a, extract_blocks(a, (2,3), keep_as_view=True))
Out[20]: True
```

Let's check out performance on a large array and verify the virtually free runtime claim as discussed earlier -

```
In [42]: a = np.random.rand(2000,3000)

In [43]: %timeit extract_blocks(a, (2,3), keep_as_view=True)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 801 ns per loop

In [44]: %timeit extract_blocks(a, (2,3), keep_as_view=False)
10 loops, best of 3: 29.1 ms per loop
```