# Making a sparse matrix containing array

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to build a sparse matrix like that:

```
         0   |   1   |   2   |
0        0   |[1,2,3]|[7,8,9]|
1     [4,5,6]|   0   |   0   |
```

using the `csr_matrix` from  `scipy.sparse` in Python.

I do it as following. It works with an 1-D array though.

`csr_matrix(([[1,2,3][7,8,9][4,5,6]], ([0,0,1], [1,2,0])), shape=(2,3))`

But I have the error `ValueError: row, column, and data arrays must be 1-D`

Is there any other package doing it?

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: One ideas is using `pandas` data frame as a matrix. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html

Comment: `scipy.sparse` is best for simple numeric values, so the matrices can be used for calculations like matrix products and linear algebra.  So your idea doesn't fit.  If you could construct such an array, what would use it for?  It's not even a good fit for `numpy` arrays, or `pandas` dataframes (though possible).

Comment: There is a block matrix format that might fit your needs.  I haven't used it much, but here's a recent answer using it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53574046/how-to-get-the-blocks-back-from-a-scipy-sparse-block-matrix/53574936#53574936

Comment: I need it to be able te classify through Logistic Regression with 3 features Because actually i'm doing the same for 1 feature.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `bsr` representation of your array.

Use an ordinary (2,3) `csr` matrix to find the `indices` and `indptr` for the blocks:

```
In [335]: M1 = sparse.csr_matrix([[0,1,1],[1,0,0]])
In [336]: M1.A
Out[336]: 
array([[0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

Define the `data` blocks.  I had to order them to match the M1 layout:

```
In [337]: data = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,1,3)[[0,2,1],:]
In [338]: data
Out[338]: 
array([[[1, 2, 3]],

       [[7, 8, 9]],

       [[4, 5, 6]]])
```

Now make a `bsr` matrix:

```
In [339]: M = sparse.bsr_matrix((data, M1.indices, M1.indptr), shape=(2,9))
In [340]: M
Out[340]: 
<2x9 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 9 stored elements (blocksize = 1x3) in Block Sparse Row format>
In [341]: M.A
Out[341]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9],
       [4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

It represents a (2,9) matrix, but the values are stored a 3 `(1,3)` blocks.  For display, and most calculations it is converted to more conventional `csr` matrix.

This information could also be stored as dictionary:

```
In [349]: adict = {}
In [350]: adict[(0,1)] = data[0]
     ...: adict[(0,2)] = data[1]
     ...: adict[(1,0)] = data[2]
     ...: 
     ...: 
In [351]: adict
Out[351]: 
{(0, 1): array([[1, 2, 3]]),
 (0, 2): array([[7, 8, 9]]),
 (1, 0): array([[4, 5, 6]])}
```

`sparse.dok_matrix` is also a `dict` subclass.  But it does not accept `dtype=object`, which would be the only way to store arrays as elements.