# divide an N*N array into square blocks (patches)

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

Im pretty new to python. I have a np array (image) of size (128x128) and I want to divide it into 64 patches of 16x16. how can I slice the array? and How can I reassemble it into a 128x128 array afterwards?

I tried this but it's adding memory expense when I try to reassemble it

```
import numpy as np
xpx = np.random.rand(5,128,128)

new=np.zeros((5,64,16,16))


for i in range(0,5):
  w=0
  for j in range(0,128,16):
    for k in range(0,128,16):
      new[i,w]=xpx[i,j:j+16,k:k+16]
      w=w+1
```

Comment: What does "adding memory expense" mean? How did you measure that? How did you reassemble it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31530106/8143158

Answer (score 0):

Split the array into 64 patches of size 16x16

```
patches = np.split(image, 64, axis=0)
```

Reassemble the patches back into a single array

```
reassembled = np.concatenate(patches, axis=0)
```