# Matlab cell2mat function in Python Numpy?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

Does numpy have the cell2mat function? Here is the link to [matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html?refresh=true). I found an implementation of something similar but it only works when we can split it evenly. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856788/slice-2d-array-into-smaller-2d-arrays).

Comment: There are no cell arrays in numpy. Expected output is probably a np.array but what is your input?

Comment: A combination of `np.vstack` and `np.hstack` can concatenate a nested list of compatible arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a sense Python has had 'cells' at lot longer than MATLAB - `list`.  a python list is a direct substitute for a 1d cell (or rather, cell with size 1 dimension).  A 2d cell could be represented as a nested list.  `numpy` arrays with dtype object also work.  I believe that is what `scipy.io.loadmat` uses to render cells in .mat files.

`np.array()` converts a list, or lists of lists, etc, to a `ndarray`.  Sometimes it needs help specifying the dtype.  It also tries to render the input to as high a dimensional array as possible.

```
np.array([1,2,3])
np.array(['1',2,'abc'],dtype=object)
np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2],[3]])
np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
```

And MATLAB structures map onto Python dictionaries or objects.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html

`loadmat` can also represent structures as numpy structured (record) arrays.

There is `np.concatenate` that takes a list of arrays, and its convenience derivatives `vstack`, `hstack`, `dstack`.   Mostly they tweak the dimensions of the arrays, and then concatenate on one axis.

---

Here's a rough approximation to the MATLAB cell2mat example:

```
C = {[1],    [2 3 4];
     [5; 9], [6 7 8; 10 11 12]}
```

construct ndarrays with same shapes

```
In [61]: c11=np.array([[1]])    
In [62]: c12=np.array([[2,3,4]])
In [63]: c21=np.array([[5],[9]])
In [64]: c22=np.array([[6,7,8],[10,11,12]])
```

Join them with a combination of `hstack` and `vstack` - i.e. concatenate along the matching axes.

```
In [65]: A=np.vstack([np.hstack([c11,c12]),np.hstack([c21,c22])])
# or A=np.hstack([np.vstack([c11,c21]),np.vstack([c12,c22])])
```

producing:

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
```

Or more generally (and compactly)

```
In [75]: C=[[c11,c12],[c21,c22]]
In [76]: np.vstack([np.hstack(c) for c in C])
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use *object arrays* as a replacement for Matlab's *cell arrays*.  For example:

```
cell_array = np.array([[np.arange(10)],
                       [np.arange(30,40)] ],
                       dtype='object')
```

Is a 2x1 object array containing length 10 numpy array vectors.  I can perform the `cell2mat` functionality by:

```
arr = np.concatenate(cell_array).astype('int')
```

This returns a 2x10 int array. You can change `.astype('int')` to be whatever data type you need, or you could grab it from one of the objects in your cell_array,

```
arr = np.concatenate(cell_array).astype(cell_array[0].dtype)
```

Good luck!