# Numpy split cube into cubes

Tags: numpy

There is a function `np.split()` which can split an array along 1 axis. I was wondering if there was a multi axis version where you can split along axes (0,1,2) for example.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Suppose the `cube` has shape `(W, H, D)` and you wish to break it up into `N` little cubes of shape `(w, h, d)`. Since NumPy arrays have axes of fixed length, `w` must evenly divide `W`, and similarly for `h` and `d`.

Then there is a way to reshape the cube of shape `(W, H, D)` into a new array of shape `(N, w, h, d)`.

For example, if `arr = np.arange(4*4*4).reshape(4,4,4)` (so `(W,H,D) = (4,4,4)`) and we wish to break it up into cubes of shape `(2,2,2)`, then we could use

```
In [283]: arr.reshape(2,2,2,2,2,2).transpose(0,2,4,1,3,5).reshape(-1,2,2,2)
Out[283]: 
array([[[[ 0,  1],
         [ 4,  5]],

        [[16, 17],
         [20, 21]]],

...
       [[[42, 43],
         [46, 47]],

        [[58, 59],
         [62, 63]]]])
```

The idea here is to add extra axes to the array which sort of act as place markers:

```
 number of repeats act as placemarkers
 o---o---o
 |   |   |
 v   v   v
(2,2,2,2,2,2)
   ^   ^   ^
   |   |   |
   o---o---o
   newshape
```

We can then reorder the axes (using `transpose`) so that the number of repeats comes first, and the newshape comes at the end:

```
arr.reshape(2,2,2,2,2,2).transpose(0,2,4,1,3,5)
```

And finally, call `reshape(-1, w, h, d)` to squash all the placemarking axes into a single axis. This produces an array of shape `(N, w, h, d)` where `N` is the number of little cubes.

---

The idea used above is a generalization of [this idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16858283/190597) to 3 dimensions. It can be further generalized to ndarrays of any dimension:

```
import numpy as np
def cubify(arr, newshape):
    oldshape = np.array(arr.shape)
    repeats = (oldshape / newshape).astype(int)
    tmpshape = np.column_stack([repeats, newshape]).ravel()
    order = np.arange(len(tmpshape))
    order = np.concatenate([order[::2], order[1::2]])
    # newshape must divide oldshape evenly or else ValueError will be raised
    return arr.reshape(tmpshape).transpose(order).reshape(-1, *newshape)

print(cubify(np.arange(4*6*16).reshape(4,6,16), (2,3,4)).shape)
print(cubify(np.arange(8*8*8*8).reshape(8,8,8,8), (2,2,2,2)).shape)
```

yields new arrays of shapes

```
(16, 2, 3, 4)
(256, 2, 2, 2, 2)
```

---

To "uncubify" the arrays:

```
def uncubify(arr, oldshape):
    N, newshape = arr.shape[0], arr.shape[1:]
    oldshape = np.array(oldshape)    
    repeats = (oldshape / newshape).astype(int)
    tmpshape = np.concatenate([repeats, newshape])
    order = np.arange(len(tmpshape)).reshape(2, -1).ravel(order='F')
    return arr.reshape(tmpshape).transpose(order).reshape(oldshape)
```

---

Here is some test code to check that `cubify` and `uncubify` are inverses.

```
import numpy as np
def cubify(arr, newshape):
    oldshape = np.array(arr.shape)
    repeats = (oldshape / newshape).astype(int)
    tmpshape = np.column_stack([repeats, newshape]).ravel()
    order = np.arange(len(tmpshape))
    order = np.concatenate([order[::2], order[1::2]])
    # newshape must divide oldshape evenly or else ValueError will be raised
    return arr.reshape(tmpshape).transpose(order).reshape(-1, *newshape)

def uncubify(arr, oldshape):
    N, newshape = arr.shape[0], arr.shape[1:]
    oldshape = np.array(oldshape)    
    repeats = (oldshape / newshape).astype(int)
    tmpshape = np.concatenate([repeats, newshape])
    order = np.arange(len(tmpshape)).reshape(2, -1).ravel(order='F')
    return arr.reshape(tmpshape).transpose(order).reshape(oldshape)

tests = [[np.arange(4*6*16), (4,6,16), (2,3,4)],
         [np.arange(8*8*8*8), (8,8,8,8), (2,2,2,2)]]

for arr, oldshape, newshape in tests:
    arr = arr.reshape(oldshape)
    assert np.allclose(uncubify(cubify(arr, newshape), oldshape), arr)
    # cuber = Cubify(oldshape,newshape)
    # assert np.allclose(cuber.uncubify(cuber.cubify(arr)), arr)
```

Comment: if i want to uncubify it what is the transpose reshape combination i need to get it back to the big cube?

Comment: @mattdns: I've added an `uncubify` function above. There is a difference in our definitions of `reverseOrder` (or what I called `order` in the `uncubify` function). It makes a difference for higher dimensional arrays. Changing the definition to `self.reverseOrder = np.arange(len(self.tmpshape)).reshape(2, -1).ravel(order='F')` will fix your code.

Comment: Great answer. May I suggest to cubify with: `einops.rearrange(x, '(x w) (y h) (z d) -> (x y z) w h d', w=2, h=2, d=2)` and uncubify with `einops.rearrange(x, ' (x y z) w h d -> (x w) (y h) (z d)', x=2, y=2, z=2)` ?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to my extra question to @unutbu's answer I think I have got the reverse to work (in case you want to split a cube into cubes, apply a function to each one and then combine them back).

```
import numpy as np
import pdb
np.set_printoptions(precision=3,linewidth=300)

class Cubify():
    def __init__(self,oldshape,newshape):
        self.newshape = np.array(newshape)
        self.oldshape = np.array(oldshape)
        self.repeats = (oldshape / newshape).astype(int)
        self.tmpshape = np.column_stack([self.repeats, newshape]).ravel()
        order = np.arange(len(self.tmpshape))
        self.order = np.concatenate([order[::2], order[1::2]])
        self.reverseOrder = self.order.copy()
        self.reverseOrder = np.arange(len(self.tmpshape)).reshape(2, -1).ravel(order='F')
        self.reverseReshape = np.concatenate([self.repeats,self.newshape])

    def cubify(self,arr):
        # newshape must divide oldshape evenly or else ValueError will be raised
        return arr.reshape(self.tmpshape).transpose(self.order).reshape(-1, *self.newshape)

    def uncubify(self,arr):
        return arr.reshape(self.reverseReshape).transpose(self.reverseOrder).reshape(self.oldshape)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    N = 9
    x = np.arange(N**3).reshape(N,N,N)
    oldshape = x.shape
    newshape = np.array([3,3,3])
    cuber = Cubify(oldshape,newshape)
    out = cuber.cubify(x)
    back = cuber.uncubify(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a  multi axis version where you can split along some given axes. But you can split it up one dimension at a time. For example like this:

```
def split2(arys, sections, axis=[0, 1]):
    if not isinstance(arys, list):
         arys = [arys]
    for ax in axis:
        arys = [np.split(ary, sections, axis=ax) for ary in arys]
        arys = [ary for aa in arys for ary in aa]  # Flatten
    return arys
```

It can be used like this:

```
In [1]: a = np.array(range(100)).reshape(10, 10)
In [2]: split2(a, 2, axis=[0, 1])
Out[2]:
[array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
       [40, 41, 42, 43, 44]]),
 array([[ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
       [45, 46, 47, 48, 49]]),
 array([[50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
       [60, 61, 62, 63, 64],
       [70, 71, 72, 73, 74],
       [80, 81, 82, 83, 84],
       [90, 91, 92, 93, 94]]),
 array([[55, 56, 57, 58, 59],
       [65, 66, 67, 68, 69],
       [75, 76, 77, 78, 79],
       [85, 86, 87, 88, 89],
       [95, 96, 97, 98, 99]])]
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed the `cubify` function from unutbu's answer written using TensorFlow functions to be able to use it as a layer in my neural network and to optimize it with `@tf.function`. I believe that someone might find it useful, therefore, I'm leaving it here. I did not test the overall functionality on different data but for my data it works great.

```
@tf.function
def cubify(inputs, output_shape):
    repeats = tf.math.floordiv(inputs.shape, output_shape)
    tmp_shape = tf.stack([repeats, output_shape], axis=1)
    tmp_shape_reshaped = tf.reshape(tmp_shape, [-1])
    range_len = tf.range(len(tmp_shape_reshaped))
    order = tf.concat([[range_len[::2], range_len[1::2]]], axis=1)
    order_reshaped = tf.reshape(order, [-1])
    output = tf.reshape(inputs, tmp_shape_reshaped)
    output_reordered = tf.transpose(output, order_reshaped)
    output_reshaped = tf.reshape(output_reordered, (-1, *output_shape))
    return output_reshaped
```