# Numpy aggregate across multiple axes

Tags: python, numpy, compression, aggregation, reduction

Let's say I have a 3d numpy array.shape of (27,27,27). I want to compress this to (9,9,9) by averaging every 3 elements across every axis simultaneously (e.g. make 3x3x3 pixels into 1x1x1).  The objective is to effectively compress by a single integer across all three axes simultaneously (with the assumption that any array will have a multiple of that integer for the shape of each axes).

My initial attempt was to use np.apply_over_axes, though I'm worried it is not getting the cubic mean of all 3 axes but instead averaging each sequentially.

```
def mean_over(arr, axis):

    np.average(arr.reshape(-1, 3), axis=axis)

the_array_small = np.apply_over_axes(mean_over, the_array, \[0,1,2\])
```

However this returns an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "\<stdin\>", line 1, in \<module\>

  File "\<\__array_function_\_ internals\>", line 180, in apply_over_axes

  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/mambaforge/base/envs/seaborn/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/lib/shape_base.py", line 496, in apply_over_axes

    if res.ndim == val.ndim:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

I'm not convinced my apply_over_axes solution gets the aggregation I'm aiming for though. Ideally the mean of each (3,3,3) component is returned.

Comment: Are those number the order of magnitude of your real data? Or just examples? (I mean, if your data are really 27×27×27, it might be better to go with quite simple numpy technique. If they could in reality be 2187×2187×2187, then it is probably more advisable to rely on convolutions techniques

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ndim' is observed because your function returns nothing. But your function doesn't work anyway, as numpy would expect your function to return something of the same dimension, or one dimension less, which your function definitely doesn't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution but take advantage of  `as_strided`

```py
a = np.arange(27**3).reshape(27, 27, 27)
tile_size = (3, 3, 3)
tile_shape = tuple(np.array(a.shape) // np.array(tile_size))
tile_strides = tuple(np.array(a.strides) * np.array(tile_size)) + tuple(a.strides)
tile_view = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
    a,
    shape=tile_shape + tile_size,
    strides=tile_strides,
    writeable=False,
)
result = np.mean(tile_view, axis=(-3, -2, -1))
```

Comment: This answer works for a general workflow as it doesn't need the output shape; it produces identical results to the one line solution from @chrslg

`def frac_tran(a, tile_size):
    tile_shape = tuple(np.array(a.shape) // np.array(tile_size))
    tile_strides = tuple(np.array(a.strides) * np.array(tile_size)) + tuple(a.strides)
    tile_view = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
        a,
        shape=tile_shape + tile_size,
        strides=tile_strides,
        writeable=False,
        )
    return np.mean(tile_view, axis=(-3, -2, -1))
    
test = frac_tran(a, (3,3,3))`

Answer (score 4):

Just a first answer (but again, depending on your answer to my comment, it could be better to rely on some convolution)

```py
arr=np.randon.rand(27,27,27)
the_array_small = arr.reshape(9,3,9,3,9,3).mean(axis=(1,3,5))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `cubify` function from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42298440/12131013) answer, you can break your array into cubes. With that result, you can then use `apply_over_axes` to get the averages and reshape for your desired result. Here I use an example of a 9x9x9 cube since it's easier to see the result that way.

```py
import numpy as np

def cubify(arr, newshape):
    """https://stackoverflow.com/a/42298440/12131013"""
    oldshape = np.array(arr.shape)
    repeats = (oldshape / newshape).astype(int)
    tmpshape = np.column_stack([repeats, newshape]).ravel()
    order = np.arange(len(tmpshape))
    order = np.concatenate([order[::2], order[1::2]])
    # newshape must divide oldshape evenly or else ValueError will be raised
    return arr.reshape(tmpshape).transpose(order).reshape(-1, *newshape)

a = np.arange(9**3).reshape(9,9,9)
c = cubify(a, (3,3,3))
res = np.apply_over_axes(np.mean, c, [1,2,3]).reshape(3,3,3)
```

Result:

```py
array([[[ 91.,  94.,  97.],
        [118., 121., 124.],
        [145., 148., 151.]],

       [[334., 337., 340.],
        [361., 364., 367.],
        [388., 391., 394.]],

       [[577., 580., 583.],
        [604., 607., 610.],
        [631., 634., 637.]]])
```