# split numpy multidimensional array into equal pieces

Tags: python, image, numpy

I'm trying to split a 9x512 image (called test) into 384 3x4 images, but trying the following code:

```
splited = test.reshape(-1,3,4)
plt.imshow(splited[0,:,:])
```

I don't get the same result as doing:

```
plt.imshow(test[0:3,0:4])
```

I would really appreciate your help :)

Comment: okay, but you need to tell us which approach gives the "correct" result?

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856788/slice-2d-array-into-smaller-2d-arrays

Comment: the correct must be plt.imshow(test[0:3,0:4]), but I'm trying to avoid for loops since I have too many images

Comment: well, you do `imshow` on your images, that will introduce much more overhead than any python-iterations.

Comment: @YohanesGultom that was what I was looking for, thank you! :)

Comment: So it looks like you want `test..reshape(3,3,128,4)`, and possibly a transpose to produce a (3,128,3,4) and reshape to (384,3,4)?