# Divide matrix into square 2x2 submatrices - maxpooling fprop

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, machine-learning, deep-learning

I'm trying to implement fprop for MaxPooling layer in Conv Networks with no overlapping and pooling regions 2x2. To do so, I need to split my input matrix into matrices of size 2x2 so that I can extract the maximum. I am then creating a mask which I can use later on in `bprop`. To carry out the splitting I am splitting my input matrix first vertically and then horizontally and then finding the maximum using `vsplit`, `hsplit` and `amax` respectively. This keeps crashing however with index out of bounds exceptions and I am not sure where the error is. Is there a simpler way to split the 24 x 24 input matrix into 144 2x2 matrices so that I can obtain the maximum.

I am doing the following to do so:

```
for i in range(inputs.shape[0]):
        for j in range(inputs.shape[1]):
            for k in range(inputs.shape[2] // 2):
                for h in range(inputs.shape[3] // 2):

                    outputs[i,j,k,h] = np.amax(np.hsplit(np.vsplit(inputs[i,j], inputs.shape[2] // 2)[k], inputs.shape[1] // 2)[h])

                    max_ind = np.argmax(np.hsplit(np.vsplit(inputs[i,j], inputs.shape[2] // 2)[k], inputs.shape[1] // 2)[h])

                    max_ind_y = max_ind // inputs.shape[2]

                    if (max_ind_y == 0):
                        max_ind_x = max_ind
                    else:
                        max_ind_x = max_ind % inputs.shape[3]

                    self.mask[i,j,max_ind_y + 2 * k, max_ind_x + 2 * h] = outputs[i,j,k,h]
```

EDIT:

This is the output produced by reshape:

[image]

What I would like instead is

```
[0 1 
 4 5]

[2 3 
 6 7]
```

and so on...

Comment: Add a sample case and show us the expected output?

Comment: @Divakar added example in edit

Comment: But what's the final expected output? This would help out with the block creation - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856788/slice-2d-array-into-smaller-2d-arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step #1 : Getting `max_ind_x`, `max_ind_y`**

We need to get the row, column indices of the max element per block -

```
m,n = inputs.shape
a = inputs.reshape(m//2,2,n//2,2).swapaxes(1,2)
row, col = np.unravel_index(a.reshape(a.shape[:-2] + (4,)).argmax(-1), (2,2))
```

**Step #2 : Setting output array with argmax places from the input**

Then, looking at your code it seems you are trying to create an output array with those `argmax` places set with values from the input array. Hence, we could do -

```
out = np.zeros_like(a)
M,N = a.shape[:2]
indx_tuple = np.arange(M)[:,None],np.arange(N), row, col
out[indx_tuple] = a[indx_tuple]
```

Finally, we could get the 2D shape back for the output and this would be a good verification step against the original input `inputs` -

```
out2d = out.reshape(a.shape[:2]+(2,2)).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(m,n)
```

Sample input, output -

```
In [291]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: inputs = np.random.randint(11,99,(6,4))

In [292]: inputs
Out[292]: 
array([[55, 58, 75, 78],
       [78, 20, 94, 32],
       [47, 98, 81, 23],
       [69, 76, 50, 98],
       [57, 92, 48, 36],
       [88, 83, 20, 31]])

In [286]: out2d
Out[286]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0],
       [78,  0, 94,  0],
       [ 0, 98,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 98],
       [ 0, 92, 48,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

Answer (score 3):

This is implemented as [`view_as_blocks`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_blocks)  in `skimage.util`:

```
blocks = skimage.util.view_as_blocks(a,(2,2))
maxs = blocks.max((2,3))
```