# Numpy dot product along specific axes

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 512x512 image array and I want to perform operations on 8x8 blocks. At the moment I have something like this:

```
output = np.zeros(512, 512)

for i in range(0, 512, 8):
    for j in rangerange(0, 512, 8):
        a = input[i:i+8, j:j+8]
        b = some_other_array[i:i+8, j:j+8]
        output[i:i+8, j:j+8] = np.dot(a, b)
```

where `a` & `b` are 8x8 blocks derived from the original array. I would like to speed up this code by using vectorised operations. I have reshaped my inputs like this:

```
input = input.reshape(64, 8, 64, 8)
some_other_array = some_other_array.reshape(64, 8, 64, 8)
```

How could I perform a dot product on only axes `1` & `3` to output an array of shape `(64, 8, 64, 8)`?

I have tried `np.tensordot(input, some_other_array, axes=([0, 1], [2, 3]))` which gives the correct output shape, but the values do not match the output from the loop above. I've also looked at `np.einsum` but I haven't come across a simple example with what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: BTW: `for i in range(0, 512, 8)` and you don't need do `i*8 : (i+1)*8` but `i:i+8`. It will be more readable.

Comment: [here's neat way to split your image into blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16858283/3595907)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you suspected, `np.einsum` can take care of this. If `input` and `some_other_array` have shapes `(64, 8, 64, 8)`, then if you write

```
output = np.einsum('ijkl,ilkm->ijkm', input, some_other_array)
```

then `output` will also have shape `(64, 8, 64, 8)`, where matrix multiplication (i.e. `np.dot`) has been done only on axes `1` and `3`.

The string argument to `np.einsum` looks complicated, but really it's a combination of two things. First, matrix multiplication is given by `jl,lm->jm` (see e.g. [this answer on einsum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089893/understanding-numpys-einsum)). Second, we don't want to do anything to axis `0` and `2`, so for them I just write `ik,ik->ik`. Combining the two gives `ijkl,ilkm->ijkm`.

Answer (score 2):

They'll work if you reorder them a bit. If input and some_other_array are both shaped (64,8,64,8), then:

```
input = input.transpose(0,2,1,3)
some_other_array = some_other_array.transpose(0,2,1,3)
```

This will reorder them to 64,64,8,8. At this point you can compute a matrix multiplication. Do note that you need matmul to compute the block products, and not dot, which will try to multiply the entire matrices.

```
output = input @ some_other_array
output = output.transpose(0,2,1,3)
output = output.reshape(512,512)
```

Comment: Although the `np.einsum` answer was accepted, it's worth noting that for my application this method was faster. Thanks!