# NumPy: 2-D array tiled, converted to a 1-D array, and have to become a 2-D array again

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

Ok, I am no an expert in numpy, so sorry if the answer is obvious, but this has been bugging me off for a few days now, so I have no other option than asking here. So, here is the input array I have:

```
a = np.array([
    [0, 0, 1, 3, 4,  5,  12, 0, 0,  0, 0,  0  ],
    [0, 0, 4, 0, 13, 0,  0,  2, 0,  0, 0,  0  ],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,  6,  7,  8, 0,  0, 0,  0  ],
    [5, 4, 9, 0, 3,  0,  7,  2, 0,  0, 0,  0  ],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0,  0,  0, 0,  0, 0,  0  ],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1,  0,  5,  7, 5,  0, 1,  0  ],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  5,  12, 3, 0,  4, 12, 3  ],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 5,  14, 0,  9, 10, 2, 0,  15 ]
])
```

It needs to be split into tiles with a size of 4x4 (which means 16 elements per tile, you'll see why this is important).
I tile it up (using Iosif Doundoulakis's `np.reshape()` method, explained [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/efficiently-splitting-an-image-into-tiles-in-python-using-numpy-d1bf0dd7b6f7), big shoutout):

```
def tiling(arr):
    # 16 - total number of elements getting into a tile
    # 4 - width of a tile
    # 4 - height of a tile
    b = arr.reshape(arr.shape[0] // 4, 4, arr.shape[1] // 4, 4, 1)
    return b.swapaxes(1, 2)
```

... and, when I call `tiles = tiling(a)`, I get a similar result:

*I've formatted the output for easier reading, the actual output looks different, but it is organised the same way.

```
[[
 [
  [[ 0] [ 0] [ 1] [ 3]]
  [[ 0] [ 0] [ 4] [ 0]]
  [[ 1] [ 2] [ 3] [ 4]]
  [[ 5] [ 4] [ 9] [ 0]]
 ]
.... this is one tile, there are 5 more ...
]]
```

which is exactly what I want my tiles to look like. Then, I flatten the tiled array, so it becomes

```
[ 0  0  1  3  0  0  4  0  1  2  3  4  5  4  9  0  4  5 12  0 13  0  0  2
  5  6  7  8  3  0  7  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  5  7
  0  5 12  3  5 14  0  9  0  0  0  0  5  0  1  0  0  4 12  3 10  2  0 15]
```

and every 16 numbers represent a tile. The next step is to pass the flatten array to an external program which returns an array with the same shape - 1 dimensional array. For now, the data is only passed to the external utility and returned by it, so the array keeps it's values.

Knowing the total number of array elements that go into a tile (16), as well as the shape of a tile (4, 4), how can I turn this 1-D array back into tiles and then create a 2-D array from those tiles, which looks like the one from the beginning?

**EDIT:**
I was out for a few days, sorry for the delay!
The thing is that I have a flat 1-D array as a result of the external utility which I want to reshape into a form, I get from the original array, so something like:

```latex
    arr (with a shape (8, 12, 1))
        |
        |  tile the array (using Iosif 
        |  Doundoulakis's method)
        V 
    tiled_arr = arr.reshape(2, 3, 4, 4, 1)
        |
        | flatten the tiled array
        V 
    tiled_arr.flatten('C')
        |
        | pass to the external utility
        V 
    it returns the same flat array, for now, but it wouldn't in the nearest future, so reformatting tiled_array is not an option
        |
        | pass it to a reshaping function in question
        V 
    It should reshape the flat array back into (8, 12, 1), which is the shape of the original array arr
```

I came up with this code yesterday:

```
def reshape(flat_array, original_array):

    a = np.array([np.split(flat_array, 16)]).reshape(original_array.shape[1] // 4, 4, original_array.shape[0] // 4, 4, original_array.shape[2])

    b = a.reshape(2, 3, 4, 4)
    return b.swapaxes(1, 2).reshape(original_array.shape)
```

... and it works, I get the result I want to. But it seems to me, it could be at least optimised a little bit.

Comment: I'm not able to run your `tiling` function. Besides `frame` being not defined, it raises `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 96 into shape (0,16,3,4,1)`

Comment: I fixed it, should be fine now. Due to copying code and hardcoding some variable values, I messed up the function, but it's fixed now, try again. Thanks for pointing this out and not letting it just sink in :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is actually as simple as another `swapaxes` and `reshape`. First, you'll need to call `swapaxes(1, 2)` *again* to undo the last call. Then just reshape back to `a`'s shape.

```py
>>> tiles
array([[[[[ 0],
          [ 0],
          [ 1],
          [ 3]],

         [[ 0],
          [ 0],
          [ 4],
          [ 0]],
          ...
          ]]])

>>> tiles.swapaxes(1, 2).reshape(a.shape)
array([[ 0,  0,  1,  3,  4,  5, 12,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  4,  0, 13,  0,  0,  2,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 5,  4,  9,  0,  3,  0,  7,  2,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  5,  7,  5,  0,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  5, 12,  3,  0,  4, 12,  3],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  5, 14,  0,  9, 10,  2,  0, 15]])
```

If you don't have `a.shape`, you can probably calculate it with something like `(S[0]*S[2], S[1]*S[3])`, where `S` is `tiles.shape`:

```
tiles.swapaxes(1, 2).reshape(x.shape[0] * x.shape[2], x.shape[1] * x.shape[3])
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand what you want exactly, but I guess you are searching for something like [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72330350/13394817) (which get `shape = (6, 4 ,4)` for your example):

```
a.reshape(a.shape[0] // 4, 4, -1, 4).swapaxes(1, 2).reshape(a.size // (4 * 4), 4, 4)
```

You need to reshape the return array to `a.size // (4 * 4), 4, 4)` (if you sure about the shapes that can be divided by 4 or 16 …), so the tiling function must change to:

```
def tiling(arr):
    b = arr.reshape(arr.shape[0] // 4, 4, arr.shape[1] // 4, 4, 1)
    return b.swapaxes(1, 2).reshape(arr.size // (4 * 4), 4, 4)

# [[[ 0  0  1  3]
#   [ 0  0  4  0]
#   [ 1  2  3  4]
#   [ 5  4  9  0]]
# 
#  [[ 4  5 12  0]
#   [13  0  0  2]
#   [ 5  6  7  8]
#   [ 3  0  7  2]]
# 
#  [[ 0  0  0  0]
#   [ 0  0  0  0]
#   [ 0  0  0  0]
#   [ 0  0  0  0]]
# 
#  [[ 0  0  0  0]
#   [ 0  0  0  0]
#   [ 0  0  0  0]
#   [ 0  0  0  0]]
# 
#  [[ 0  0  0  0]
#   [ 1  0  5  7]
#   [ 0  5 12  3]
#   [ 5 14  0  9]]
# 
#  [[ 0  0  0  0]
#   [ 5  0  1  0]
#   [ 0  4 12  3]
#   [10  2  0 15]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the benefits of Iosif Doundoulakis' approach is that the tiled array and the original array share memory.

```
original_array = np.array([
    [0, 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 4, 0, 13, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [5, 4, 9, 0, 3, 0, 7, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5, 7, 5, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 12, 3, 0, 4, 12, 3],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 14, 0, 9, 10, 2, 0, 15],
])

tile_rows, tile_cols = tile_shape = (2, 4)

grid_rows, grid_cols = grid_shape = (original_array.shape[0] // tile_shape[0],
                                     original_array.shape[1] // tile_shape[1])

tiled_array = original_array \
    .reshape((grid_rows, tile_rows, grid_cols, tile_cols, 1)) \
    .swapaxes(1, 2)

print(np.shares_memory(tiled_array, original_array))  # True
```

`tiled_array` is a view of `original_array`; any in-place modifications of `tiled_array` also apply to `original_array`:

```
tiled_array[0, 0] = 99
print(original_array)
```

prints

```
[[99 99 99 99  4  5 12  0  0  0  0  0]
 [99 99 99 99 13  0  0  2  0  0  0  0]
 [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  0  0  0  0]
 [ 5  4  9  0  3  0  7  2  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  1  0  5  7  5  0  1  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  5 12  3  0  4 12  3]
 [ 0  0  0  0  5 14  0  9 10  2  0 15]]
```

As others have pointed out, the transformation can be reversed by swapping the axes back and reshaping,

```
recovered_original_array = tiled_array \
    .swapaxes(1, 2) \
    .reshape((grid_rows * tile_rows, grid_cols * tile_cols))

print(np.all(recovered_original_array == original_array))  # True
```

The three arrays all share memory.

```
print(np.shares_memory(recovered_original_array, original_array)) # True
```

However, this useful property is destroyed when you flatten the array with the `flatten` method, because `flatten` always returns a copy rather than a view,

```
flat_array = tiled_array.flatten()
print(np.shares_memory(flat_array, original_array))  # False
```

The `reshape` method, called with `-1` as its argument, will return a flattened view if possible, but will otherwise return a copy. In this case, it returns a copy.

```
flat_array = tiled_array.reshape(-1)
print(np.shares_memory(flat_array, original_array))  # False
```

Either way, you can easily recover `tiled_array` from `flat_array`,

```
recovered_tiled_array = flat_array.reshape((grid_rows, grid_cols, tile_rows, tile_cols, 1))
print(np.shares_memory(recovered_tiled_array, tiled_array))  # False
print(np.all(recovered_tiled_array == tiled_array))  # True
```

As far as I know, there is no way to make a flat array view of the original array with the order you require. You can, however, make a flat view of the tiled array, and work on that.
To do so, make a *copy* of `tiled_array`

```
tiled_array = original_array \
    .reshape((grid_rows, tile_rows, grid_cols, tile_cols, 1)) \
    .swapaxes(1, 2).copy()

print(np.shares_memory(tiled_array, original_array))  # False
```

allowing a flat *view* of the same,

```
flat_array = tiled_array.reshape(-1)

print(np.shares_memory(flat_array, tiled_array))  # True

flat_array[:] = function_on_flat_array(flat_array)  # changes apply automatically to flat_array
```