# after slicing matrix, how to average between connecting arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a matrix A of size 256x256.

I have divided it in 16 arrays of 32 by 32, keeping its original array connections.

Then I want to average the border of each array with its adjacent  connection.

---

Let's say,  we have a matrix A of size 12x12, (then I want 16 chunks of 3x3)
I am using blockshaped ( [Slice 2d array into smaller 2d arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856788/slice-2d-array-into-smaller-2d-arrays)) to slice the matrix

```
np.random.seed(365)
c = np.arange(144).reshape((12, 12))

L=blockshaped(c, 3, 3)
```

Visually:

```
c=[[ 0   1   2 |  3   4   5  | 6   7   8   | 9  10  11]
  [ 12  13  14 | 15  16  17  | 18  19  20  | 21  22  23]
  [ 24  25  26 | 27  28  29  | 30  31  32  | 33  34  35]
------------------------------------------------------
  [ 36  37  38 | **39  40  41**  | 42  43  44  | 45  46  47]
  [ 48  49  50 | **51  52  53**  | 54  55  56  | 57  58  59]
  [ 60  61  62 | **63  64  65**  | 66  67  68  | 69  70  71]
------------------------------------------------------
  [ 72  73  74 | 75  76  77  | 78  79  80  | 81  82  83]
  [ 84  85  86 | 87  88  89  | 90  91  92  | 93  94  95]
  [ 96  97  98 | 99 100 101  | 102 103 104 | 105 106 107]
------------------------------------------------------
  [108 109 110 | 111 112 113 | 114 115 116 | 117 118 119]
  [120 121 122 | 123 124 125 | 126 127 128 | 129 130 131]
  [132 133 134 | 135 136 137 | 138 139 140 | 141 142 143]]
```

If I take the chuck marked with **

```
39  40  41
51  52  53
63  64  65
```

How can I average the value of the boundaries?

`39  40  41` with `27  28  29`

`63 64 65` with `75 76 77`

and

`39  51  63` with `38  50  62`
`41  53  65` with `42  57  69`

any ideas will help me a lot

Comment: Perhaps you should run your convolution before you split the arrays.

Comment: Hello Tim, do you mean doing the average first?

Comment: Yes, your average is basically a convolution.  It would be a lot easier to keep track of the coordinates.