# average of "row"and "column" in list

Tags: python, list, average

I am trying to make an new list with the averages from every n row and column. my original list looks like this:

```
\list =
\[\[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3\],
\[4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6\],
\[7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9\],
\[0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2\],
\[3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5\],
\[6,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,8\]\]

n = 3\
```

my new list should look like this:
list = [[4,5,6],[3,4,5]]

i tried it in al lot of ways but i get lost along the way

Comment: Can you please share with us what you have tried and the problem?

Comment: it's in python. i tried to make a total and than divide it by n**2; but i don't know how to make it go through the whole list so i can make the new list

Comment: i used for and while loops to make the total (for a in list and while b < n)

Comment: Can you explain to us how do you get the expected results? Just one example to make the logic clear. It's a 6x9 matrix..

Comment: From what I understand, your list represents a 2D array, which you want to partition into sub-arrays each of size `n * n`, calculating the average of each. Is this correct?

Comment: @user21283023; that's correct. and avery row should be a sub-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Note that this solution relies on the [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/whatisnumpy.html) package, and assumes that your list is represented as a 2D NumPy array.)

---

#### Input Data

```py
import numpy as np

lst = [[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
       [4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6],
       [7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9],
       [0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2],
       [3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5],
       [6,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,8]
      ]

n = 3

# Convert the list of lists to a 2D array.
arr_2d = np.array(lst)

print(arr_2d)
```

---

#### Solution

##### Partitioning a 2D array

There appears to be no simple method to partition a 2D array into 2D sub-arrays in Python. But [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16858283/21283023) provides a function that can accomplish this:

```py
def blockshaped(arr, nrows, ncols):
    """
    Return an array of shape (n, nrows, ncols) where
    n * nrows * ncols = arr.size

    If arr is a 2D array, the returned array should look like n sub-blocks with
    each sub-blocks preserving the "physical" layout of arr.
    """
    h, w = arr.shape
    assert h % nrows == 0, f"{h} rows is not evenly divisible by {nrows}"
    assert w % ncols == 0, f"{w} cols is not evenly divisible by {ncols}"
    return (arr.reshape(h//nrows, nrows, -1, ncols)
               .swapaxes(1,2)
               .reshape(-1, nrows, ncols))
```

Output of `blockshaped(arr_2d, n, n)` (will be represented as a 3D array):

```
[[[1 1 1]
  [4 4 4]
  [7 7 7]]

 [[2 2 2]
  [5 5 5]
  [8 8 8]]

 [[3 3 3]
  [6 6 6]
  [9 9 9]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [3 3 3]
  [6 6 6]]

 [[1 1 1]
  [4 4 4]
  [7 7 7]]

 [[2 2 2]
  [5 5 5]
  [8 8 8]]]
```

##### Calculating average of partitions

After applying the `blockshaped()` function, you can use [`np.mean()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) to calculate the averages of each sub-array, and then [`np.array_split()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html) to then group them as sub-lists according to the rows of the original array.

I've created a function to accomplish all of this:

```py
def avg_partitions(arr, n):
    """
    Partitions a a 2D array into n x n sub-arrays and outputs 
    as a list of lists each of their average values grouped row-wise.
    """

    # Partition into 2D sub arrays each of size n x n
    sub_arrs = blockshaped(arr, n, n)

    # Create a list made up of the mean of each of these sub-arrays
    avg_values = [np.mean(a) for a in sub_arrs]

    # Work out how many sublists to split the resulting chucks into (Number of Rows / n)
    n_lists = arr.shape[0] // n

    # Split the average into sub-lists (made of arrays)
    avg_sublists = np.array_split(avg_values, n_lists)

    # Convert the arrays to lists
    avg_sublists = [a.tolist() for a in avg_sublists]

    return avg_sublists
```

Output of `avg_partitions(arr_2d, n)`:

```
[[4.0, 5.0, 6.0], [3.0, 4.0, 5.0]]
```

Comment: thank you! this is going to help me with my project!